# Tapestry make Select mandatory

Tags: tapestry

I want to create a dropdown List with Select and I want to have a default value in it (something along the lines of "choose something").

The default I get but how do I "force" the user to choose from the select input?
Should I catch it's value when I commit? Is there no cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "validate".

Works like this:

```
<t:zone t:id="modelZone" id="modelZone">
         <t:if test="yourZoneTestVariable">
           <p>
              <t:select t:id="selectId" model="yourModel" validate="required"/>
           </p>
         </t:if>
      </t:zone>
```

Hope this helps you.

More information is here (though it is hard to read for tapestry beginners):
http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Select.html

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! Feel really dumb to not have looked the docs through more...

Comment: If you also add blankOption="Always" and blankLabel="Choose something" you'll get your default value too. (only validate="reqiured" forces a selection).